# Bootstrap 3 fullscreen carousel not fullscreen in landscape

Tags: css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, carousel

I made a carousel to fill 100% height and width of browser and it does that fine on a desktop or in protriate mode on a mobile but when switched to landscape the display breaks. I made a bootply but it doesnt show the error im refering to. Maybe its caused by the form I have added?

http://www.bootply.com/BKl0fXVMrj

You can see the actual error here. Open dev tools select a iphone4,5,6 galaxy s4,5.. pretty much any current smart phone and you will see what I mean.

http://www.casouza.com/homelist

Comment: I believe this is caused by the fact that you now need to scroll on landscape mode, you could try making it so you don't have to scroll but that may not be practical. Otherwise it may be worth trying to set the carousel to a fixed position?

Answer (score 0):

After my previous comment I looked deeper into this, try the code below in your CSS.

```
#bg-slide-carousel .carousel-inner {       

    position:fixed;

}
```

This makes the background carousel stay with the viewport. I've tested this in the chrome dev tools emulator with the site you posted and it appears to work fine.